# Sacar diferencia entre 2 campos de un select Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @dt date = '09/04/2019';
DECLARE @dta date = '08/04/2019';
SELECT t1.IdCliente, t1.IdProducto,t1.UmbralVariacion,t1.Saldo,t2.Saldo as anterior,Diferencia = (t2.Saldo - t1.Saldo), Porcentaje =((t2.Saldo*12)/100)
FROM 
    (select PC.IdCliente,IdProducto, Saldo,S.UmbralVariacion from PRODUCTO_CLIENTE PC inner join CLIENTE C on PC.IdCliente=C.Id
    inner join ASIGNACION_SEGMENTO ASI On C.id=ASI.IdCliente and IdAsesor=5 inner join SEGMENTO S on S.Id=ASI.IdSegmento
        where Fecha_imp=@dt) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (select PC.IdCliente,IdProducto,Saldo from PRODUCTO_CLIENTE PC inner join CLIENTE C on PC.IdCliente=C.Id
    inner join ASIGNACION_SEGMENTO ASI On C.id=ASI.IdCliente and IdAsesor=5
    where Fecha_imp=@dta) t2
ON (t1.IdCliente = t2.IdCliente and t1.IdProducto= t2.IdProducto)
where t2.Saldo is not null
order by t1.IdCliente
```

[image: Consulta]

Quiero que la consulta me devuelva solo los valores en los cuales la diferencia entre el campo saldo y el campo anterior sea +- el 10%

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade tu código, no das muchas opciones para alguna edición a tu código

Comment: ¿El 10% del actual o del anterior?

Comment: Osea si el campo saldo tiene una variacion del +- 10% del campo anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar una condición en el where para comprobar que la diferencia entre los saldos es menor que el 10% del saldo anterior. Para evitar complicaciones con saldos mayores o menores podemos utilizar la función ABS (valor absoluto).

Por ejemplo, una versión simplificada sería:

```
create table prueba
(
producto varchar(25),
saldo_actual decimal(8,4),
saldo_anterior decimal (8,4),
)

insert into prueba values ('Shampoo',10.0, 9.0)
insert into prueba values ('Pasta dental',15.5, 2.3)
insert into prueba values ('Cepillos marca SO',110.5, 110.49)
```

Ahora, mostramos el 10% del saldo anterior y la diferencia:

```
select producto, saldo_anterior, saldo_anterior*0.10 as '10% del saldo anterior', abs(saldo_actual-saldo_anterior) diferencia
from prueba
```

Esto nos devuelve:

```
producto                  saldo_anterior 10% del saldo anterior diferencia  
------------------------- -------------- ---------------------- ----------- 
Shampoo                   9.0000         0.900000               1.0000      
Pasta dental              2.3000         0.230000               13.2000     
Cepillos marca SO         110.4900       11.049000              0.0100      
Hilo dental               10.0000        1.000000               1.0000
```

Podemos observar que solamente los cepillos y el hilo dental tienen una variación que es menor o igual al 10% del saldo anterior. Y ahora agregamos la condición para obtener dichos resultados:

```
select *
from    prueba
where   abs(saldo_actual-saldo_anterior) <= saldo_anterior*0.10
```

Con el resultado esperado:

```
producto                  saldo_actual saldo_anterior 
------------------------- ------------ -------------- 
Cepillos marca SO         110.5000     110.4900       
Hilo dental               9.0000       10.0000
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvió mucho

Answer (score 0):

Se puede lograr de manera sencilla agregando un BETWEEN en tu WHERE.

```
WHERE t1.Saldo BETWEEN t2.Saldo * .9 AND t2.Saldo * 1.1
```